# DLQ messages out of order

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have 2 ActiveMQ JMS consumer queues consumer1 and consumer2.

Dead letter queues are enabled for both queues mainly for avoiding poison messages continuous retry.

Issue is now consumer2 messages should be processed in order. Where as messages going to DLQ could be processed out of order later.

Any suggestions how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear; the only way to guarantee order is to process them in order (concurrency=1) and don't use any prefetch.

If you prefetch messages, rejected messages might go behind the prefetch.

Turning off prefetch will severely impact performance.